# Joomla huge idle time on load

Tags: joomla, loading

we are trying to figure out with my friend why we are have all the time over 15s idle time on load as you can see in [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/002kq.jpg)

We are using Joomla version 3.5.1 and Land Box theme. Any idea why we have such a huge idle time on loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a webpage test view](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160417_0W_13B/) of the same page.

There's a 10sec wait until until the first byte, my first suspicion for this is that the server may be overloaded.

Then there's close to another 10 seconds until the page is loaded, and the reason for this is the large number of files -- about 100 in total (40 JS files, 37 images, and 40 CSS and others)

Hope this helps!

Comment: hmm and is it possible that something is wrong with .htaccess file? some wrong caching or something like that? about those JS files etc, we know that and we will reduce that later, but for now we want to solve that beginning idle time. We have one of the best hosting here in our Country, so i dont think that server will be overloaded because for example wordpress theme had loads in less then 3s

Comment: > hmm and is it possible that something is wrong with .htaccess file?  .. if you've customised the .htaccess file, what about temporarily replacing it with the default .htaccess file and comparing results?

Comment: If you're thinking that the problem isn't with the hosting, have you tried different Joomla caching options to see what effect they have? https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/cache/

Comment: that was what we were looking for, thanks a lot, it solved our problem